# Security Codesigning Framework for iOS, missing Asn1 files?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, security

I am trying to do local receipt validation on my iOS application using the following code : https://gist.github.com/sazameki/3026845

However, there are includes in there

```
#import <Security/SecAsn1Coder.h>
#import <Security/SecAsn1Templates.h>
#import <Security/SecRequirement.h>
```

That I cannot process, even after adding Security.framework to my xCode project. All the SecAsn1 files are not present in the Security.framework that I'm adding to my project.

I did find the sources of everything I'm requiring here https://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_asn1/libsecurity_asn1-29908/lib/ but there HAS to be a better way than just getting the source from there file after file ?

Any Apple / xCode expert that can give me a hand ? I'm starting to lose sanity over this issue :)

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

Ok my bad, I realized this was a MacOS sample code and not an iOS sample code.
It seems like these security functions are not available for iOS.

I'll find an alternative.

Comment: I know it's been a few years since you posted this... I'm just starting to get into receipt validation for the very first time (moving a paid app to premium... did you ever find a solution that worked?

I'm finding that there is not much out there in terms of a package or a Pod that is installable and ready to go.  Unless I'm just missing something totally obvious.